# Proof that an open set is pathwise connected if and only if it is connected (complex analysis)

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have the following question:
[image: page1]
I am new to topology, and using it in proofs, and I am wondering if I can get a sketch of both part 1 and part 2, or a discussion of it. I know the definitions of connectedness(it is not a separation) and openness.
I understand that part 1 is asking to prove if $\Omega$ is connected. I don't have an understanding of the intent of part 2, and how to go about both.

Comment: Connected and Locally Path Connected imply Path Connected. This implies your result (along with the behavior of path connected components on open sets)

Answer (score 1):

The first part shows one direction: if $\Omega$ is path-connected then $\Omega$ is connected. This also holds for non-open $\Omega$, and in fact in any topological space. It needs that $[0,1]$ is connected (a fact you’ve been asked to reprove essentially in this exercise), and thus if $p:[0,1] \to \Omega$ is the path from $w_1$ to $w_2$, then $\Omega_1 \cap p[[0,1]], \Omega_2 \cap p[[0,1]]$ is a non-trivial disconnection of the connected space $p[[0,1]]$ (by continuity), and this contradiction shows that $\Omega$ cannot be disconnected and hence is connected.

The second part uses that if $z \in \Omega_1$, there is a whole ball $B(z,r) \subseteq \Omega$ and then all points in $B(z,r)$ can *also* be reached by a path (inside $\Omega$) from $w$, just like $z$, by taking as the last stage the line segment from $z$ to such a point (which lies inside the (convex!) ball), and so even $B(z,r) \subseteq \Omega_1$ and so the latter set is open. The argument for $\Omega_2$ being open uses a similar idea with straight line segments, to show that if $z \in \Omega_2$ (so cannot be reached) any $B(z,r) \subseteq \Omega$ also consists of unreachable points so that $B(z,r) \subseteq \Omega_2$. Connectedness then implies one of the $\Omega_i$ is empty and $\Omega_1$ is not (constant path to $w$ shows $w \in \Omega_1$) etc.

Comment: In the above for part 1,do I have to prove that ${\Omega_{1} \cap p[0,1]} \cap {\Omega_{2} \cap p[0,1]  is non-empty? which proves $\Omega$ is connected? Is a non-trivial disconnection a connection? Also, what how is continuity used in this part?

Comment: @curious_analyst $p$ continuous plus $[0,1]$ connected implies $p[[0,1]]$ connected. $w_2 \in \Omega_2 \cap p[[0,1]]$ as $w_2= p(1)$ and so bith are non-empty.

Comment: Thank you @HennoBrandsma